# How can I hide/remove/delete windows Caption Buttons like Close Button (X ) and minimize, maximize

Tags: windows, caption, frame

I'm trying to get tired of hiding or removing the title bar and buttons for minimizer, maximize and close.

I did a lot of research on the internet, but I was unable to find a solution.

I can't find any suitable solution.

Microsoft says F11, but it doesn't it actually do what I need.
I mean to hide it permanently **<kbd>F11</kbd>** not Full Screen It.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't without 3rd party software. Software recommendations are off topic on [su].

Comment: Those are special fonts, built-in by Windows / Microsoft and used in EVERY legitimate Windows Application there is. Why do you need to get rid of them as they are fundamentally necessary for us.